# Looks like Busybox shell was not doing quotes removal

Tags: linux, shell, adb, quotes, busybox

It is about following setup: Linux machine, bash, adb, embedded Linux target system with Busybox.
For target system following applies:

```
adb shell echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

adb shell echo $0
/bin/sh
```

The problem is my find command in some script does not find anything (it has been proved by other means that items being looked for in fact do exist on target). My command:

```
adb -s $AdbID shell find  / -type f \( -name "'"*audio*"'" -or     -name "'"*alsa*"'" \) \
 \( -path "'"/usr/lib/*"'" -or -path "'"/usr/bin/*"'" -or -path "'"/etc/*"'" \)
```

If to debug with echo echo gets following string as input arguments:

```
$ adb -s $AdbID shell echo find  / -type f \( -name "'"*audio*"'" -or -name "'"*alsa*"'" \) \
\( -path "'"/usr/lib/*"'" -or -path "'"/usr/bin/*"'" -or -path "'"/etc/*"'"  \)
find / -type f ( -name '*audio*' -or -name '*alsa*' ) \
( -path '/usr/lib/*' -or -path '/usr/bin/*' -or -path '/etc/*' )
```

*Note: above transcript uses escaped newlines so you dont need to scroll much here, however those are not used in original command.*

I guess same will apply to find if to remove echo from command string.
For me it looks like Busybox was not doing the quotes removal as myself used to have in Bash, after expansions of all other kinds. Ash as it seems to be Busybox shell, in its manual no word reg. quotes removal was found, so no idea how ash works in this regards.

#

If to replace Linux host with Windows desktop machine + dos command line, remaining elements as in case above* the command works fine. One can figure out difference at following point:

*) actually also other target system, however on this side no intentional changes so both setups should be identical regarding target system.

If to debug with echo echo gets following string:

```
c:\adb_shell>adb -s 2233445 shell echo find  / -type f \
\( -name "'"*audio*"'" -or -name "'"*alsa*"'" \) \
\( -path "'"/usr/lib/*"'" -or -path "'"/usr/bin/*"'" -or -path "'"/etc/*"'"  \)
find / -type f ( -name *audio* -or -name *alsa* ) \
( -path /usr/lib/* -or -path /usr/bin/* -or -path /etc/* )
```

Here the command gets from shell the string of input arguments with quotes removed.

I realize just the minute as myself writes this Q that command grouping will also not work as expected (busybox shell will consume paranthesis so 'find' won't receive them), let's address this question in other scope. Possibly command has more errors of this kind.

I believe the lack of quotes removal in case of two Linux shells in a chain is also real problem for my command string. What are possible reasons, solutions?

Comment: Are you saying that the output of `echo "'"*audio*"'"` is `*audio*`?

Comment: If you want to escape an arbitrary string such that a shell will pass it through unmodified, Python's `pipes.quote()` will do that for you. Try: `python -c 'import sys, pipes; print(pipes.quote(sys.stdin.read()))' <<'EOF'`, followed by your shell code and then an `EOF`, to get something you could substitute literally into a shell command line to pass that content through so to reach another shell.

Comment: Or you could just pass the script to the inner shell on stdin, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in

```
"'"*audio*"'"
```

the asterisks are **not** escaped from the shell. The shell will happily glob them, should a file matching `*audio*` be in the current working directory. If the `'` are really part of the filenames, you want to use `"'*audio*'"` instead. Then `find` will seach for files named `'*audio*'` (where `find`, not the shell, does the globbing for `*`).

If you simply want to find files matching `*audio*` (audio anywhere in the name), then use `-name "*audio*"` etc.

It would help if you told us exactly what the file names you want to find are.

Comment: "asterisks are actually not escaped" You are right, how i could be that blind. However the -name part makes currently zero troubles as in working dir fortunately no files matching these patterns. -path parts raise troubles as filename expansion at host where 'adb shell' is executed finds matching items resulting in 'find' receiving a mesh. Form presented in Q is one of multiple tries.

Comment: \( -path /usr/lib/* -or -path /usr/bin/* -or -path /etc/*  \) was used as most first form. It lead to successfull filename expansion on adb shell host. Therefore was adapted to \( -path \"/usr/lib/*\" -or -path \"/usr/bin/*\" -or -path \'/etc/*\'  \), it's true asterisks stay unquoted however escaped-quote pre- and suffixes prevented adb shell host from successfull filename expansion.

Comment: It looks like my command string passes two shells chained. One of desktop machine, one of embedded system. Everytime the string is subject of expansions conducted by shell. If a special character needs to survive up to the goal command it needs 2-coats protection, one coat for each shell. Is my understanding right?

Comment: bash makes globs expansion before quotes removal, so unquoted asterisks won't expand to valid files due to escaped-quote preffix and suffix. Is this true?

Comment: Story has one yet element (sorry for that, two whole days of troubleshooting my find command string): `set -f` is used on host which runs `adb shell ...` to prevent that host's shell from file name expansion on `-path ...` and `-name ...` arguments. So adb client side should be free from filepath expansion.

Comment: @Na13-c It looks like all your headaches are caused by *two* shells doing quote removal. If it is feasible with adb, put the find command in a script, send that script to the device and have it executed by the shell on the device. A lot less quoting pain.